# Prevent feet from moving for a Unity character from a Mixamo animation

Tags: unity, animation

So my question isn't about root motion, but rather just keeping the feet in place on the ground for a Mixamo animation... I tried to just delete the feet and toes in avatar configure, but nope... I am wondering if there is some sort of simple way to have an animation affect all but the feet?

Comment: You can try this asset: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/umotion-pro-animation-editor-95991 Not sure about this, but worth having a look: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.animation.rigging@0.2/manual/index.html Or just do it in your 3D modelling software.

Comment: Are you looking for an [Animation Mask](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationMaskOnImportedClips.html)?

Comment: I don't know if it is a simple way, but you can do this with Animation Rigging package. Just put Two-Bone IK constraints on feet, position them as you want and they will stay in place regardless of animation.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be with animation layers. Create a new layer in the animator window and give it an avatar mask that only uses the upper body. That way, when you play an animation that layer the feet will not move